How to start the Ktor Server when the application get launch
In my project I have a module(ktor server project).
I need to start the server when app launch. What I tried and my codes are below.

MainActivity.kt

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private val ktorServer = KtorServer()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera)

    ktorServer.startServer()
}

override fun onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy()
    ktorServer.stopServer()
}
}


KtorServer.kt

class KtorServer {

private var server: ApplicationEngine? = null

fun startServer() {
    server = embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080) {
        module()
    }.start(wait = false)
//embeddedServer(Netty, port = 8080,host = "127.0.0.1", module = Application::module).start(wait = false)
}

private fun Application.module() {
    routing {
        get("/") {
            call.respondText("Hello, Ktor!", ContentType.Text.Plain)
        }
    }
}

fun stopServer() {
    server?.stop(1000, 10000)
}
}


build.gradle

def ktor_version = '2.0.0'
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-content-negotiation:$ktor_version")
implementation("io.ktor:ktor-serialization-kotlinx-json:$ktor_version")


What problem do you have with your approach?

when open the app nothing happen. startServer function getting called then no other response. @AlekseiTirman

I can able to Start the server via terminal and can hit the api in postman. Everything works fine. But I want to start the same server when app launch.

Can you test if the URL for the server is accesuble in the browser on the device where the server is started?

yes it is working in device browser. Now I realise about localhost!!. Also test in postman with IP of device with same wifi connected and its working. Thank you @AlekseiTirman
